# How to replace text preceded by a specific word using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `str = "label 'CEN,MID' labelAlignment [CEN,MID] label
'CEN,MID'"`

I want to replace the CEN with center and MID with middle only if the preceding word is labelAlignment.

Comment: so what would be the result?

Comment: And what have you tried? And what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a regex solution? The second occurence of `CEN` and `MID` have brackets which can be used to search for:

```
var str = "label 'CEN,MID' labelAlignment [CEN,MID] label 'CEN,MID'";
var res = str.replace("[CEN", "[center");
res = res.replace("MID]", "middle]");
```